# Proportional control: steady state explanation

Tags: control-system, pid-controller

In this [video](https://youtu.be/wkfEZmsQqiA?list=PLn8PRpmsu08pQBgjxYFXSsODEF3Jqmm-y&t=382), a scenario is given to show the failings of using solely proportional control.

Consider a drone that must be made to hover at an altitude of 100m. The RPM required to hover the drone is 100 RPM for the propellers. On the ground, the error is max and produces a large response which decreases as the drone rises. At h = 100m, the response is 0 and the drone falls down, which increases the response and again makes it rise up. Finally, it settles to a steady state, which has been given for different proportional gains.

1. Why does the drone settle at a lower height? When it is moving up for the nth time, shouldn't it reach till h = 100m to stop the propellers so it can fall to rise again?
2. Why can't this problem be solved by just programming the controller to increase its response by 100rpm?

Answer (score 2):

Proportional (only) control in general requires steady-state error to produce a certain steady-state output.

If a bias is added (called manual reset) you can null that error out under a certain set of conditions, but if something changes (setpoint, perhaps there's an updraft, etc.) then some error will reappear.

In cases where proportional control is adequate, the proportional band will be relatively small, perhaps a few percent, so with the bias it's quite possible to maintain a PV within <1% under a fairly wide range of conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are maybe some erroneous ideas being interpreted here, as a result of the kind of storytelling being used -- this is a limitation of the method, where one can misinterpret it as a behavior of the system.  Namely: the idea that position steps around.  Read this as either: descriptions of snapshots in time (e.g.: the drone moves up, so its error reduces, so it keeps moving up, but more and more slowly, etc.), or hypotheticals where we set initial conditions (starts from GND, starts from 100m, etc.) and watch what happens afterward.

In all cases, what you're expected to infer is that there is a continuous trajectory connecting between those points, and that the state variable is always centered with respect to its final position (ideally, it approaches that point asymptotically).

What's not obvious, is how fast the drone could rise/fall, or how far it might overshoot the position in the process, or if it's even stable at all (it could overshoot, overcompensate for that increased error, and it oscillates faster and further away with each pass).  We require a plant transfer function to solve for this.  Once it is specified, the trajectory for any initial condition can be plotted; and rather than a story of snapshots, we have a perfectly defined curve with respect to time.

This will probably become clearer as you learn more about control theory.  So don't worry about it too much, keep your mind open that there are multiple ways to describe what is ultimately the same simple (but rather abstract) phenomena, and eventually your understanding will become clear.

In summary:

1. There's no "nth time", it's a continuous system; it might be better to have phrased it as, "as it moves closer, the controller output decreases" -- eventually and continuously, it approaches the final position.
2. It can be offset, but realize the input is arbitrary.  What if it were commanded to hover at 1m instead?  Now its error causes it to crash into the ground!  Most control applications have a variable input (setpoint), and must work approximately equally well for any value in that range.  It can be viable when not much operating range is needed.

---

Kind of a counterexample to this explanation:

We do in fact make use of (indeed quite extensively these days) systems where a continuous description doesn't necessarily apply.  For example, perhaps the plant is continuous as usual, but the controller literally functions only by taking repeated snapshots (it is discrete time sampled).  This is the domain of DSP (digital signal processing).  Generally, DSP must be done so that the change between successive samples is small enough, lest the error between successive samples become divergent (i.e., numerical instability).  That is, the sample rate must be fast enough to capture, not just the regular gradually-varying values of the system, and not even just its peak values (or a close enough approximation to them), but indeed the curvature between points (to a similar degree of approximation).  DSP systems therefore tend to use quite high sample rates relative to their bandwidth.

(Failing to sample a system fast enough, can result in quite dramatic errors; some physics-based games for example, where something happens a little too quickly/abruptly, and suddenly a model ragdolls over the horizon!)

But this is not actually a counterexample, because verbally describing such a system in this way, while it would be extremely tedious (if your name isn't Zeno), the seemingly smooth change between points would quickly become apparent.

There is, I think, didactic value in tedious or repetitious descriptions like this -- I can't bring an example to mind, but I recall having heard/read it used before.  It's maybe a more common approach when the repetition is suddenly/dramatically broken, like -- to pick math topics, the sequence [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ...](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/StrongLawofSmallNumbers.html), or a [Borwein integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borwein_integral), etc..

Answer (score 0):

> *At h = 100m, the response is 0 and the drone falls down, which
> increases the response and again makes it rise up. Finally, it settles
> to a steady state, which has been given for different proportional
> gains.*

No, this is not how this will work even with a lot of inertia built in to the drone. You can model it as an electrical problem using op-amp, voltage sources and components: -

[image]

So there is a demand of 1 volt set after 1 second that feeds an op-amp that has a variable gain (currently set at 32). The clipper after the op-amp keeps its output between 0 volts and 2 volts. This is followed by an offset of 1 volt. It represents the minimum hover RPM. Then there is drone inertia and finally, after another clipper negative feedback is applied. The output represents the height of the drone: -

[image]

> *Why does the drone settle at a lower height? When it is moving up for
> the nth time, shouldn't it reach till h = 100m to stop the propellers
> so it can fall to rise again?*

Because what was being described is a first-order system (as enacted by my ideal op-amp). Even with a lot of inertia there can be no overshoot.

> *Why can't this problem be solved by just programming the controller to
> increase its response by 100rpm?*

You can do all sorts of things to make up the difference between steady-state actual and demand but, you need to understand classical control theory first and recognize an order of a system. For instance if the order of the system were a 2nd order type where R1 has an unfeasibly large inductor placed in series you would get overshoot: -

[image]

But, the steady state response would end up the same as the first order system.